# What is the difference between the variable 2X and the two identically distributed variable X+X?

Tags: probability

Not sure if I phrase the question quite right, but lets says there is a random variable ${X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)}$, what would be the difference between a multiple of the variable and the sum of the same amount of the variable? Examples would be appreciated, since our textbook doesn't elaborate. As context, I was wondering why ${Var(X+X) \neq Var(2X)}$, at least according to my textbook.

Comment: Do you mean $X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are iid under the normal distribution? If not, they should mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X+X$ and $2X$ are exactly the same.

What you probably are asking is how the above quantity differs from $X + Y$, where $Y$ is an independent random variable with the same distribution as $X$.

To understand the difference, it is easier to consider a simpler scenario, where $X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ (i.e. it takes values $1$ and $0$ with equal probability $1/2$).

- On one hand, $2X$ only takes two values: $0$ and $2$ (with equal probability $1/2$).
- On the other hand, $X + Y$ takes values $0, 1, 2$ with probabilites $1/4, 1/2, 1/4$ respectively.

The difference is that in $2X$, you only have one source of randomness, and you are doubling whatever you get. In $X + Y$, you have two separate sources of randomness, so there are opportunities for things to "cancel" in the sum. This is a rough explanation of the intuition for why $\text{Var}(2X) > \text{Var}(X+Y)$.

Comment: but what would it mean to have 2 of X? do we just "double" the value of the possible outcomes? if so then I think I understood

Comment: @Newb Yes, whatever outcome you get, you multiply it by $2$.

Comment: ok that would make much more sense, thank you!